# Where to put generic Database Tables on Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to start with Django.

I'm developing an App. This App is called "Directory" and will store
info about websites.

I must to create a database table called "Genders", but this is a
generic database table and could be used in other App.

My question... how to deal with this kind of situation in Django? And
in wich model I shuld put this database table?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django doesn't really offer you place where things that are commonly used all over the project can live. I think the most common approach to solve this is to create a 'project'-app, which holds such project-relevant things like models, templatetags or widgets for example...

Comment: I generally create an app called `core`.

Answer (score 1):

In django, you don't (generally) create database tables. You create models, and let the django ORM create tables for you.

To prevent having two tables in your database called gender, django will prefix the model name with the name of the app. Thus, if your app was called `foo`, your model class was `Gender`, you would have `foo_gender`. But, you don't need to know this.

As for the specific case of Gender: I wouldn't bother storing this in the database in a special table. They don't make new genders anymore. If you need to store a field containing a gender, then just use `django.db.models.CharField`, with a `choices=(('M',"Male"),('F',"Female"))`.  Or if you do it lots, then create a new field.

If it is something you do need to be able to add dynamically to the database, then either abstract it out into a reusable app, or as someone else mentioned, create a sundry/project/utils app.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. How can I define "choices=(('M',"Male"),('F',"Female"))" without defining database fields? Best regards,

Comment: In the tables where you'll be using gender, you'll add a database field to store the gender value.  Docs for choices: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#choices